# Add value in ENUM column in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a table that contains an enum field:

```
public function up()
{  
  Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
  {  
    $table->enum('user_type', ['superadmin', 'other'])->default('superadmin');     
  }
```

I want to add one more value that is admin. How can I add this? Please give me a query to update the enum value.

Comment: is there a option that you can freshly migrate as you can add third value to it when you create a table columns again from scratch

Comment: Unknown column type "enum" requested. while using composer require doctrine/dbal

Comment: Drop the column and create again.

Comment: thanks alot.Now working